# Rust backslash in '' not terminated

Tags: rust

in my rust program, I need to declare a mutable variable called start and assign it the value of a backslash later on.

```rust
let mut start = '\';
```

however, the compiler throws this error:

```
error[E0762]: unterminated character literal
  --> src/main.rs:35:19
   |
35 |   let mut start = '\';
   |
```

I have already tried using ``and "" instead of '' but the error persists. Why is this??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to escape the `\` like so: `'\\'` to get a `char` or like this: `"\\"` if you want to have a `&str`
If you later want to edit that variable like the `mut` suggests you probably want a proper `String` like this:
`String::from("\\")`